# FormCollection Empty on Form Post in ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am posting a very simple form using a method I have used frequently in the past. It may be easier to show my code rather than type a lengthy explanation. Here's the HTML:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("CreateMarketingType", "ListMaintenance"); %>
    <div id="ListMaintenanceContainer">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Marketing Type Id</th>
                <th>Marketing Type Name</th>
            </tr>                    
                <%foreach (MarketingType marketingType in ViewData.Model.MarketingTypes) %>
                <%{ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= marketingType.MarketingTypeId.ToString() %></td>
                        <td><%= marketingType.MarketingTypeName %></td>
                    </tr>
                <%} %>
        </table>
        <div>
            <fieldset id="fsSaveNewMarketingType">
                <legend>Add New Marketing Type</legend>
                <label for="txtNewMarketingTypeName">New Marketing Type Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="txtNewMarketingTypeName" />
                <input type="submit" value="Save" id="CreateMarketingType" />
            </fieldset>
        </div>                    
    </div>
<% Html.EndForm();%>
```

And here's the controller code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CreateMarketingType(FormCollection form)
{
    string newMarketingTypeName = Request.Form["txtNewMarketingTypeName"].ToString();

    MarketingType newMarketingType = new MarketingType() { MarketingTypeName = newMarketingTypeName };

    _marketingTypeRepository.AddNewMarketingType(newMarketingType);

    return View("ListMaintenance", GetModel());
}
```

The submit button posts the form, and the method is invoked, but the form object defined in my parameter is empty. I have also tried Request.Form and I get the same result. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

None of your inputs have a name attribute. No name = not in the FormCollection.

Comment: Ouch - that's what I get for growing up on WebForms!! I thought the id attribute passed the values through on the form. Thanks for the reply!!

Comment: This is surprising as everything has seemingly been pointing towards using the id only. Things not as they seemed..to me anyway..

Comment: @Mark, this is required per the HTTP spec. `id` = how to find it in the DOM. `name` = what gets submitted in the `form`.

Comment: Sure enough, he's right!  (Link love: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2 ) controls need a 'name' attribute when posting.  +1 for helping me stop pull my hair out.

Comment: This really help me a lot. In my case, I have tried several methods to submit the form, but the formcollection content was always empty. After trying the add the name attribute in the tag, it works. Great!

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and then realised I had disabled all the INPUT controls before I submitted the form (as a UX feature).

Comment: When you disable the fields, does that remove them from the FormCollection?  I seem to be having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wish I could post this as a simple comment, but I don't have that priviledge...  I added all my name attributes, and still no joy.  Remember to add your name attribute to your form itself.  Must use the overload for HTML.BeginForm that accepts htmlAttributes.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question is already answered. Following is another approach I used in a MVC view, when the form collection was empty. Using JavaScript / jQuery, it sets name-value pairs to a hidden control which gets appended to the form.

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
 $("#btnExport").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                //Append the parameter to the form
                var practiceVal = $('#Practice').val();
                $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                   .attr('name', "Practice").attr('value', practiceVal)
                   .appendTo('#formHome');

                //Submit
                $('#formHome').submit();
            });
```

**Form**

```
 <form id="formHome" method="post">
 </form>
```

Refer [**Forms**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2)

> When a form is submitted for processing, some controls have their `name` paired with their current value and these pairs are submitted with the form