# How to add additional fields to form before submit?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, post, field

Is there a way to use javascript and JQuery to add some additional fields to be sent from a HTTP form using POST?

I mean:

```
<form action="somewhere" method="POST" id="form">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#form").submit( function(eventObj) {
    // I want to add a field "field" with value "value" here
    // to the POST data

    return true;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - add additional parameters on submit (NOT ajax)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530635/jquery-add-additional-parameters-on-submit-not-ajax)

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Yes.You can try with some hidden params.

```
  $("#form").submit( function(eventObj) {
      $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden")
          .attr("name", "something")
          .attr("value", "something")
          .appendTo("#form");
      return true;
  });
```

Comment: `.appendTo(this)` would probably be better.

Comment: @jcuenod original `appendTo('#form')` is much better, because such approach allows submit another form with values from this one.

Comment: You'll have to add some extra logic to avoid accumulating these input with each submit.

Comment: You'll probably want to remove the input element before you add it in case it already exists `$(this).find("input[name="+"something"+"]").remove();`

Comment: If it's not AJAX the form and the appended field is gone on submission.

Answer (score 64):

Try this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(eventObj) {
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="value" /> ');
    return true;
});
```

Comment: I need to add a file field dynamically. I tried having type=file, and the value also as the file (I'm using WebKitDirectory, so I actually get the file objects), however it never seems to pass it. The input text always gets passed though. Please help me out!

Comment: My preferred answer due to using `this` instead of the redundant `#form`

Answer (score 18):

```
$('#form').append('<input type="text" value="'+yourValue+'" />');
```

Answer (score 13):

You can add a `hidden` `input` with whatever value you need to send:

```
$('#form').submit(function(eventObj) {
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="someName" value="someValue">');
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 12):

May be useful for some:

**(a function that allow you to add the data to the form using an object, with override for existing inputs, if there is) [pure js]**

(form is a dom el, and not a jquery object [**jqryobj.get(0) if you need**])

```
function addDataToForm(form, data) {
    if(typeof form === 'string') {
        if(form[0] === '#') form = form.slice(1);
        form = document.getElementById(form);
    }

    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    var name;
    var value;
    var input;

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        name = keys[i];
        // removing the inputs with the name if already exists [overide]
        // console.log(form);
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(form.elements, function (inpt) {
             if(inpt.name === name) {
                 inpt.parentNode.removeChild(inpt);
             }
        });

        value = data[name];
        input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('name', name);
        input.setAttribute('value', value);
        input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');

        form.appendChild(input);
    }

    return form;
}
```

## Use :

```
addDataToForm(form, {
    'uri': window.location.href,
     'kpi_val': 150,
     //...
});
```

you can use it like that too

```
var form = addDataToForm('myFormId', {
    'uri': window.location.href,
     'kpi_val': 150,
     //...
});
```

you can add # if you like too ("#myformid").

Comment: It is a timesaver. I checked it with a simple form. It works!

Comment: Careful when removing inputs with the same name in a form with radios and checkboxes because uncecked fields may remove checked ones

Answer (score 11):

This works:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');

form = form.serializeArray();

form = form.concat([
    {name: "customer_id", value: window.username},
    {name: "post_action", value: "Update Information"}
]);

$.post('/change-user-details', form, function(d) {
    if (d.error) {
        alert("There was a problem updating your user details")
    } 
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but there is no redirect to result page.

Comment: this should work:
    `$('body').append(form);
    $(form).submit();`

Comment: This was the most helpful to me, because I have a large number of generated fields and I don't want to create hidden fields for each.

Answer (score -2):

Expanding upon Khawer's answer, you could refrain from using jQuery - for consistency, eg.
`<input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="value" />`