# How to send value from JS to PHP handler together with values from other form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form with some input buttons(type="text") and submit button. I also want to implement rate function, so I have found plenty of jQuery plugins (for example this one http://www.jqueryrain.com/?ws9XtnKy). But I can't understand, how can I send rate value to .php handler together with other data, which is in a different form, when submit button is clicked. Can somebody explain it to me? Do you have any ready solutions?

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
<input type="text" name="booktitle" placeholder="Title"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>'



  <script>
   var x;
   </script>
```

Comment: Show your code at least, and explain what stops you from adding all data to one form?

Comment: Because in fact it will be just a JS variable. How can I put it into same form?

Comment: @u_mulder I will add some code.

Comment: `$( 'form' ).append( '<input type=" ... ' )`

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809056/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-form-before-submit