# Python Flask Get Data Attribute From Form

Tags: python, html, forms, post, flask

Hopefully there is a very simple answer to this problem. I want to get data from a POST in flask that is not your standard textfield value. The trick to this is that I want to try and find a solution without using javascript, I could easily do that but Im attempting to only use python.

This is not my specific example but instead a simplified one.

I want to get the value of "data-status"

```
<form action="/myurl/" method="post">
    <div data-status="mydatahere" class="classname"></div>
</form>
```

Python

```
@app.route('/myurl/', methods=['POST'])
def myurl():
    #python to get 'data-status' value here.
```

Thanks so much to anyone that can provide an answer.

Comment: You can't. That isn't sent to your server when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks! Ill use javascript instead like I figured I would need to. Was just curious if there was a possible python answer.

Comment: Can `request.form` get the value of 'data-status'? BTW:'data-status' must has a `name`.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass it in as a URL parameter via the action attribute of your form, e.g.:

```
<form action="/myurl/?data-status=mydatahere" method="post">
    <div class="classname"></div>
</form>
```

And then pick it up in flask like so:

```
@app.route('/myurl/', methods=['POST'])
def myurl():
    #python to get 'data-status' value here as my_var variable:
    my_var = request.args.get('data-status')
```

Not sure if this works in your situation but it is how I solved a similar problem for myself :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If you're for some reason unable to change your HTML, I suggest you to make it on submit event.

Take a look at this other question: [How to add additional fields to form before submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809056/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-form-before-submit)