# Adding fields to form with JQuery submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

I am trying to add form fields to a form before submitting it using JQuery.  I've already tried the following stackoverflow questions and they have not worked:

[How to add additional fields to form before submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809056/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-form-before-submit)

[jQuery - add additional parameters on submit (NOT ajax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530635/jquery-add-additional-parameters-on-submit-not-ajax)

If I don't add any parameters to the form, the submit works:

```
$('.submit_button').click(function(){
    $('#quote_form').submit();
});
```

The code above works.  Once I try to add a field, however, the form does not get submitted.  It is not reaching the server.  Here is the code I am using:

```
$('.submit_button').click(function(){
    console.log('1');
    $("#quote_form").submit( function(eventObj) {
      console.log('2');
      $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="dog" value="rover" /> ');   
      return true;
    });
});
```

The first console.log appears in the console but the second does not.  How do I get this code to work?

Comment: What do you mean the form does not get submitted? Do you see a post in the network tab?

Comment: There is no post in the network tab.

Comment: You're never submiting the form.

Comment: I know.  I'm trying to figure out why the form is not submitting.

Comment: I meant you where not doing anything to make it submit :-). See the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not submitting the form. Try this:

```
$("#quote_form").submit( function(eventObj) {
   $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="dog" value="rover" /> ');   
   return true;
});

$('.submit_button').click(function(){
    $("#quote_form").submit();
});
```

`$(..).submit(handler)` does not submit but only register a handler function for the submit event. You need to call `$(..).submit()` without parameters for it to submit.

Comment: Thanks.  This works except the information that I need to put into the input is "this" IE "submit_button" because there are two buttons that can be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

the second console.log() not appears because you don't stop submitting.

```
$('.submit_button').click(function(){
    console.log('1');
    $("#quote_form").submit( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('2');
        $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="dog" value="rover" /> ');     
        $("#quote_form").submit();
    });
});
```

I hope this will help you!