# How to use Bootstrap dropdown as an HTML form <select>

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I think I may be being dense. I wanted to use a Bootstrap dropdown button to select from a list of names. Can I do this in plain HTML and/or very simple jQuery?

IE I want to use a Bootstrap dropdown as an HTML form `select` input.

```
<button class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1565"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Select Client
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" name="xx-selectClient" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1565">
    <li><a id="yy-lloydBrayton">Lloyd Brayton</a></li>
    <li><a id="yy-muiThreet">Mui Threet</a></li>
    <li><a id="yy-wilsonBritton"> Wilson Britton</a></li>

    <li><a id="yy-gilbertMinto">Gilbert Minto</a></li>
    <li><a id="yy-thomasinaLaney">Thomasina Laney</a></li>
```

I put the form together to look OK (be easy to use etc) and then set about cleaning up to make it functional. The basic BS "Select" is rather ugly so would rather use a dropdown list if I can. Everything else is going OK but I am stuck as to how to use a dropdown as a select.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Cory and previous SO poster this works for me and I thought might be helpful for someone else

```
<script>
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
var selectId = $(this).attr('id')
    $('#formId').submit(function(eventObj) {
        $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='selectClient' value="+selectId+"/> ");
        return true;
    });
})
</script>
```

If you want the text not an `id` then, in the third line use:

```
var sel = $(this).text()
```

**EDIT:** Adarsh's contribution below is off topic but brilliant. I was was trying to pass values but Adarsh's solution adds the name of the selected user to the button providing essential user feedback. So you end up with:

[image]

Thanks for a perfect solution people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rszens8z/1/

```
  <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"      id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- expanded="true">
     Dropdown
     <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a id="yy-lloydBrayton">Lloyd Brayton</a></li>
     <li><a id="yy-muiThreet">Mui Threet</a></li>
     <li><a id="yy-wilsonBritton"> Wilson Britton</a></li>

     <li><a id="yy-gilbertMinto">Gilbert Minto</a></li>
     <li><a id="yy-thomasinaLaney">Thomasina Laney</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

You can change the look of it with some built in BS CSS http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Comment: Sorry I am trying to turn a dropdown into a form select. This seems to be another version of dropdown. Thanks but I am not worried  about the look I am trying to attach a form function to it! Unless I have missed the point.

Comment: Do you want to submit the selection from the DD like a form? What do you want to happen once they select?

Comment: Cory yep I want it to act like an `<form><select><option> etc`

Comment: Ok, I updated the link to the fiddle. You can listen for the click on the drop down selection, then you can do whatever you want with the selection that was made.

Comment: Cory - first - fantastic. Didn't think I could get the info into the form and then - voila! - I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809056/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-form-before-submit 

and. with a bit of hacking got the thing to work! I am amazed and HUGELY in your debt.

Comment: One last question. Am I right in thinking that jQuery/JS variables cannot be: `aaa-bbb`? It seems a hyphen cost me 30 mins. I could not find a reference to acceptable variable formats.

Comment: Yes, see here for JS variable name rules http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is what you wanted..:D

```js
function dropdownMenu1565Set(val){
 if(val.innerHTML!=""){$('#dropdownMenu1565').val(val.innerHTML);$('#dropdownMenu1565').html(val.innerHTML);}
 else{$('#dropdownMenu165').val('');$('#dropdownMenu165').html('Select Client');}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1565"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Select Client
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" name="xx-selectClient" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1565">
    <li><a id="yy-lloydBrayton" onclick="dropdownMenu1565Set(this);">Lloyd - 1 _ $ Brayton</a></li>
    <li><a id="yy-muiThreet" onclick="dropdownMenu1565Set(this);">Mui Threet</a></li>
    <li><a id="yy-wilsonBritton" onclick="dropdownMenu1565Set(this);">Wilson Britton</a></li>
    <li><a id="yy-gilbertMinto" onclick="dropdownMenu1565Set(this);">Gilbert Minto</a></li>
    <li><a id="yy-thomasinaLaney" onclick="dropdownMenu1565Set(this);">Thomasina Laney</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Adarsh thanks but all working fine now - where were you yesterday when I needed you LOL. But hopefully others will find this question useful and your answer looks quite elegant (though it has me confused). Thanks - Now if you would just like to sort out my next mess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752771/cannot-get-jquery-call-right-for-eternicode-bootstap-datepicker I would forever be in your debt.

Comment: Why dont you mark this an answer (If it works..) LOL.:D

Comment: Ardash thanks saw the page missed the specific bit "Names can contain letters, digits, underscores, and dollar signs." as I was so tired. So now I know - no dashes ... which is slightly annoying.

Comment: It looks like the code is still working with all these conditions

Comment: Ardash sorry do not understand your code and you did supply it AFTER the answer had been provided. Not sure of the etiquette for that. But it was not an "answer" for me. Will take advice.

Comment: Adash finally got this working. Completely NOT what I was looking for (passing a form variable through from a dropdown) BUT added to the solution above make a really excellent little tool. Will add a jsfiddle in a day or two. BRILLIANT! Thanks

Comment: Adarsh (sorry for calling you Ardash!) your code is very useful (not what I was asking for but 100% useful). Question: Is there an easy way for the value to be passed back and displayed on using the browser's back button. At present doing form validation after submit I know tidy will come later) and everything comes back fine but obviously not the jQuery driven button. If this is easy great - if not pls do not bother as this will all get done "properly" when the code goes live. Once again thanks for a great  addition to this solution

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again. Moving toward "production" and this code of yours has no doubt saved me 4-10 hours. Mahalo nui loa as we say over here

Comment: @BeNice hi! You should consider mark this question as the correct one.