# Cannot get jQuery call right for eternicode Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have been trying out the eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker). I tried out the sandbox (http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) and just wanted to use the "Component" version with "Today" highlighted.

I have two problems which I think are the same thing: 1) the date doesn't show up when you click on the glyphicon only when you click in the `input` space and 2) I cannot get the "Today" highight working.

I am 99% sure it is the jQuery call that is wrong. I have tried all sorts to get it to fire as per Sandbox etc but my JS/jQuery is just not up to the job.

(The timepicker (https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker) works fine without a jQuery launch script for now).

Part of the problem is that when I download a zip from GitHub there are two .less files both of which (I think) are Bootstrap2.

Any help gratefully recieved.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3 colFlushL">
    <label class="control-label" for="zaq-timeSimple">Time</label>
    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker colFlush ">
        <input id="timepicker1" type="text" name="arse"
               class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-3 colFlush"  id="zaq-startDate">
    <label class="control-label" for="zaq-startDate">Start Date</label>
    <div class="input-group colFlush">
        <input type="text" class="form-control date" name="datepicker"
               data-provide="datepicker">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the latest version of my jQuery attempt which is I am 95% sure horrendous.

```
<script>
$('.datepicker.date').datepicker.(
    {
        todayHighlight: true
    }
)
</script>
```

NB According to phpStorm date is NOT a class defined anywhere which I presume includes the .less file

PS I should have said the two date pickers on the page ARE 100% passing the value of the dates through with the form.

Comment: there is no element with both classes `.datepicker.date`. It is looking for an element which have `class="datepicker date"`

Comment: Tried `<div class="input-group colFlush datepicker date">` but that did not do it. What does the last "datepicker" in `$('.datepicker.date').datepicker.(` signify?

Comment: can you prepare a demo in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: OK thanks guys. Will try that in the morning (I find jsfiddle a little intimidating and not really sure what you would want there). I tried a simple id selector `$('#zaq').datepicker.(` but no joy. Have x-ray and barium meal in morning so trying to go to bed.

Comment: OK don't know what I am doing but http://jsfiddle.net/stevenhomer/gw6a5sn2/ also real page is here which might be easier http://moviemaui.com/sane30/beta30/createTransmissionSimple.php. But my confusion comes from a) not knowing what parts of https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker to use and b) confusion on the triggering jQ. I'm a basic app user - I use simple js file, a simple bit of CSS and then duplicate a tiny bit of JS to get it working. This app seems to be v well maintained but it requires Bower or NPM or Grunt etc which r over my head for the simple project I am building.

Comment: Now a new problem. Trying the page on an Android phone and the timepicker is all over the place. I know asking "has anyone found a good datepicker etc" is verboten here but where on StackExchange can I try and find a consensus please. I just need a half decent timepicker and datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this was a typo (or more accurately newb lack of jQuery understanding!!)

```
$('.datepicker.date').datepicker.(
```

should have been

```
$('.datepicker.date').datepicker(
```

IE I stuck in an extra period. (And that cost me at least two hours! D'oh!)