# Flask - getting the text inside an html select option tag instead of the value of the option

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a select tag in my form

```
    <select name="source" id="source">
        {% for row in inode.inodes %}
            <option value="{{loop.index}}">{{ row.inode.title }}</option>
```

While the values are used to order the options, what interests me is the text in the option.

however, in the python code,

```
source = request.form['source']
```

Is preferring the value.
How can I retrieve the text inside the tag instead?

Comment: You can keep value and text same

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple solutions to this.Try to implement one of these can see if it works

1. You can keep value and text same
2. Fetch value via jquery/js in frontend and then post it in variable to access them in flask
3. Set data-attribute for options and send them to flask. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809056/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-form-before-submit)

Comment: Could you explain how can I do this in 3 option with data-attribute?