# Merge two form values and send

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

I'm having trouble submitting this merged forms.
If I use the `mainForm.submit()` which is commented out now, it submits, but when I use submit with `$.ajax` it doesn't reach `success`. I tried also `mainForm[0].submit(function() {...}` without any luck.
Can somebody help me with that?

```js
$(function() {
  var mainForm = $('#mainForm'),
        modalForm = $('#modalForm');


  $('#submitBtn').on('click', function() {
    //mainForm.submit();
    
    console.log($('#mainForm, #modalForm').serialize());

    mainForm.submit(function() {
      var action = $(this).attr('action');

      $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#mainForm, #modalForm').serialize(),
        success: function() {
          console.log('success');
          //window.location.replace(action);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="mainForm" action="/page/2" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD" />
  <input type="hidden" name="recurring" value="true" />
</form>

<div class="modal">
  <form id="modalForm">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="Foo" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="Bar" />
    <input type="text" name="emailAddress" value="foo.bar@domain.com" />
  </form>
  
  <button type="button" id="submitBtn">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: AJAXify this form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need to use submit, just use `ajax` on clicked button function:

```
$(function() {
  $('#submitBtn').on('click', function() {
      var action = $('#mainForm').attr('action');

      $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#mainForm, #modalForm').serialize(),
        success: function() {
          console.log('success');
          //window.location.replace(action);
          return true;
        }
      });
      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: OMG, you are so right! How could I miss that?! Thanks @Navand!

Comment: One remaining question about the script. If the url is defined by the action attribute, why do I need the window.location.replace(action)? Without it it doesn't go to the next page.

Comment: As I know, If you don't want to move user to new location or refresh the page, You use ajax, otherwise you normally submit your form with form.submit, that post your data and also redirect user to new address, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809056/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-form-before-submit) for update form before submit.