# Add Parameter and use a modelAttribute

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I use a modelattribute in my form and controller.

```
<form:form action="/admin/editingBook" modelAttribute="editingBook">
...
...
</form:form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/admin/editingBook")
public String updateBook(@ModelAttribute BookBean bookBean) {
}
```

I would like to add an information who are not in my modelAttribute, something like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/admin/editingBook")
public String updateBook(@ModelAttribute BookBean bookBean, @RequestParam("bookName") String bookName) {
}
```

not sure how to do it on the jsp side and controller side

Comment: Add it as a request parameter. Simply add a hidden field with the name 'bookName' and it will be passed as a request parameter. Or using javascript add it to the URL `${baseUrl}+?bookName=${yourBookName}`

Answer (score 0):

Where the book name would come?

Controller side :

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/admin/editingBook/{bookName}")
    public String updateBook(@ModelAttribute BookBean bookBean, @RequestParam("bookName") String bookName) {
    }
```

Comment: what if you set attribute in http request scope, pass the request and retrieve the attribute?

Comment: i tried  

    var oldBookTitle = $('#bookTitle').data('old-book-tile');  
    $('#editingBook').submit(function() {  
      $(this).attr("action", "${editBoolUrl}" + oldBookTitle);
      $(this).dialog('close');
    });

but nothing is called on the server side

Comment: that is not proper way to append, here take a look at this:
1)for proper call to make ajax http://www.raistudies.com/spring/spring-mvc/ajax-spring-mvc-3-annonations-jquery/
2) how to append additional data for the call
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530635/jquery-add-additional-parameters-on-submit-not-ajax